# count array in class is not working

Tags: php

i have code like this;

```
  <?php

class count{

    public function hitung()
    {
        $angka = array("bmw", "volvo", "honda");
        return count($angka);

        echo $angka();
    }

}

 ?>
```

then i am edited like this

```
  <?php

class count{

    public function hitung()
    {
        $angka = array("bmw", "volvo", "honda");
        echo count($angka);


    }

}

 ?>
```

i hope the browser is show value count number of arrays, but when i acces the localhost, the browser cannot showwing anythinhg,,
how to calculate the number of arrays in class and the number is show on browser
??

Comment: Don't give your `class` the same name as a built-in function. Also, this code does nothing, as the `hitung` method is never called.

Comment: Count is in built in function change your class name

Comment: It doesn't matter about `count`. [Working demo](https://eval.in/1016543)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

you use `class` so you can create first `class object` and than call `function using class object`

like,

```
$c = new count;
echo $c->hitung();

<?php
class count{
    public function hitung()
    {
        $angka = array("bmw", "volvo", "honda");
        return count($angka);

    }

}
$c = new count;
echo $c->hitung();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is working fine. Define your class as follows:

```
class count
{
    public function hitung()
    {
        $angka = [ 'bmw', 'volvo', 'honda' ];
        return count($angka);
    }
}
```

And then simply use this when you want to output:

```
$counter = new count;
echo $counter->hitung();
```

It's also worth noting that `$angka` should probably be a member variable, so the refactored code below may be better:

```
class count
{
    private static $angka = [ 'bmw', 'volvo', 'honda' ];

    public function hitung()
    {
        return count( self::$angka );
    }
}
```

See this [working demo](https://eval.in/1016543).